# Android Room dynamic Where clause

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I would like to create fully dynamic where clause in Room.

Is there any way to make something like code below to work and return number of updated columns?

```
@Query("UPDATE table SET column = ${xyConstVal} WHERE :where")
fun updateTable(where:String):Int
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create fully dynamic where clause in Room.

Instead of using @Query annotation in dao you could try using @RawQuery which accepts SupportSQLiteQuery as value then write your query in old fashioned way

> Is there any way to make something like code below to work and return
>   number of updated columns?

A method, annotated with @Insert can return a long. This is the newly generated ID for the inserted row. A method, annotated with @Update can return an int. This is the number of updated rows.

In your case you can combine both